# How to rebind a stateful allocator in C++?

Tags: c++, allocator, stateful

Assuming a situation where we have a stateful allocator and creating a copy is not desirable, I assume it would have to be supplied by reference (to any given struct or class), so:

```
element_allocator_type &allocator = supplied_allocator;
```

How does one rebind this allocator reference to another type without losing it's statefulness ie. without creating a copy? Can we in fact do so? If:

```
typedef typename std::allocator_traits<element_allocator_type>::template rebind_alloc<unsigned char> uchar_allocator_type;
```

(for example) is the type we're rebinding to, what is the line to create a rebinded allocator reference?

```
uchar_allocator_type &rebound_allocator = ???
```

Cheers-

Answer (score 3):

> Assuming that a stateful allocator has to be supplied by reference (to any given struct or class)

Well there's your problem. The C++ standard library allocator model requires no such thing. Allocator types are [*required* to be copyable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/allocator.requirements), even stateful ones. The expectation is that the copy of the allocator will behave like the original and memory allocated by one can be freed by the other (which is what `==` means when applied to two allocators).

In short, if your allocator is stateful, it must provide shallow copying behavior. And that's how you implement `rebind`: the new allocator may have a different allocation type, but it references the same allocation machinery.

Comment: They must even be noexcept-copyable, and it is expected to be cheap. `std::shared_ptr` looks like the right way to manage any state if needed.

Comment: Okay, but just because an allocator is copyable, doesn't mean that's a useful thing to do. I would assume that if the user is supplying a stateful allocator that means there's some state they want retained. I'll re-write the question so that it makes it clear that not copying the allocator is required behaviour (and I believe that would be the case for almost all situations when using a stateful allocator). If there's not a solution to doing so (rebinding an allocator reference) that's fine.